# Starting a sentence with Why, but not as a question

Tags: informal-writing

A grammatically correct way to ask someone a question would be:

> Why **are you** still here?

If I want to make a statement (instead of a true question), such as, *You've been here too long* or *Your comments are annoying*, or *You're either a troll or a quarrelsome person*, would *"Why **you are** still here"* (meaning- why do you continue arguing with everyone) be acceptable in a conversational English?

*Do you know why you're still here?* is grammatically correct, but I don't want to know if he knows, I just want to express an annoyance with the person.

Comment: "Why" can be used as an exclamation at the beginning of a sentence to express surprise or annoyance - _Why, it's Jane! I didn't expect to see you_ - but Britannica Dictionary calls this usage 'somewhat old-fashioned'.

Comment: Yeah, I'd associate "Why!" (e.g. "Why, you're still here!") with Scarlett O'Hara and other Southern belles. Exclamations like that are very specific to time, region, and possible other factors (class, race, gender...)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wh- clauses vs Relative clauses](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/348692/wh-clauses-vs-relative-clauses) See also [how to categorize the string "Where to go" in the sentence "Where to go is the question." Relative clause, Interrogative clause, Adverbial clause?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/203036/how-to-categorize-this-phrase-relative-clause-interrogative-clause-adverbial/209772#209772). 'Why you are still here' is a noun phrase (subtype fused relative), and rarely works as a sentence substitute.

Answer (score 1):

When **why** is used as an exclamation, it is followed by a declaration not a question.

> Why, your nose is bleeding!
>
> Why, it's Santa Claus!
>
> Why, you're still here!

But it expresses more surprise than annoyance. You'd have to supply an annoyed tone of voice to make sure it isn't interpreted as merely mild surprise, or some additional words:

> Why, you're still here!  I thought I asked you to leave.

Comment: *Why, thank you!*

Answer (score 0):

The construct is grammatical and understandable when qualified by an appropriate context. Using the example circumstances you give, we could write:

“*Why you are still here, after the argumentative behaviour you have shown,  I cannot imagine.*”

Or

“*Why you are still here is a mystery to those who value civilised debate.*”

And

“*Why you are still here is that you have no home to go to.”*